# ¿Cómo reemplazar un ciclo For?

Tags: r, bucles, data, eficiencia

Ya me habeís ayudado en un problema parecido, con una solución que reducia el tiempo de ejecución de manera considerable.

Ahora el problema que tengo es que necesito consultar el valor que hay en una variable pero en una fila anterior y no se como hacer para eliminar el for y así ganar en tiempo de ejecución.

```
FLAG <- c("A","B","C","A","D","D")
VALOR <- c("GRA","VE","DT","RT","MM","SS")
datos <- data.table(FLAG,VALOR)
datos <- datos[,VALOR3:=rep("vacio",nrow(datos))]
for (i in 2:nrow(datos)){ 
    if(datos$FLAG[i]=='B' & datos$FLAG[i-1]=='A') datos$valor3[i-1] <- datos$valor[i] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La mejor idea sería usar operaciones sobre vectores desde mi punto de vista:

```
FLAG <- c("A","B","C","A","D","D")
VALOR <- c("GRA","VE","DT","RT","MM","SS")
datos <- data.table(FLAG,VALOR)
datos <- datos[,VALOR3:=rep("vacio",nrow(datos))]
len <- nrow(datos)

index <- datos$FLAG=="A" & c(datos$FLAG[-1],"-") == "B"
datos$VALOR3[index]<-datos$VALOR[c(FALSE,index[-len])]
```

Primero hallas los índices que cumplen la condición y luego cambias esos valores. Como los vectores son de diferente longitud pues tienes que añadirle un elemento para que se puedan comparar.

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos.

Las dos soluciones son buenas, me han sido de gran utilidad, no solo para este problema sino para otros similiares.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, te comento que tienes un problema en tu código, recuerda que los nombres de variables son sensibles a minúsculas/mayúsculas. Dentro de tu `for` estás llamado a `valor`y `valor3` en minúsculas, entiendo que es un error tipográfico nomás. Otra forma interesante de resolver el problema es haciendo uso de la función [`ifelse()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html) que es vectorizada:

```
FLAG <- c("A","B","C","A","D","D")
VALOR <- c("GRA","VE","DT","RT","MM","SS")
datos <- data.table(FLAG,VALOR)
datos <- datos[,VALOR3:=rep("vacio",nrow(datos))]

datos$VALOR3 <- ifelse(datos$FLAG =='A' & c(datos$FLAG[-1], NA) == 'B',
                       c(datos$VALOR[-1], NA), 
                       NA)
datos

   FLAG VALOR VALOR3
1:    A   GRA     VE
2:    B    VE     NA
3:    C    DT     NA
4:    A    RT     NA
5:    D    MM     NA
6:    D    SS     NA
```

- Verificamos cada valor de `datos$FLAG` contra un vector que representa el mismo `datos$FLAG` pero desplazado un valor `c(datos$FLAG[-1], NA)`
- Si la condición se da, retornamos el valor correspondiente al vector de valores de `datos$VALOR` desplazado también un índice: `c(NA, datos$VALOR[-nrow(datos)])`.